# Wordpress Custom post meta meta values not saving

Tags: php, wordpress

I m creating a wp plugin which supports custom post type. In that i have created a custom meta box..when i enter the metabox values it will not save into the admin dashboard as well as database. Can any one help me out this.
Thanks..

```
//enter code here 
function astestimonial_meta_box($post_id)
 {
  wp_nonce_field('astest_meta_box','astest_meta_box_nonce');
  $clientname = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_clientname_value','true');
echo'<label for="client_name_val">';
_e('Name: ', 'astestimonial_textdomain');
echo'</label>';
echo'<input type="text" id="client_name_val" name="client_name_val" value="'.esc_attr($clientname).'" />';

}
//Save meta data code
function astest_save_client_info($post_id)
{
if(!isset($_POST['astest_meta_box_nonce']))
{
    return;
}

if(!wp_verify_nonce($POST['astest_meta_box_nonce'],'astest_meta_box'))
{
    return;
}

if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
{
    return;
}

if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) 
    {
        return;
    }

}
else
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) 
    {
        return;
    }
}

if(  !isset( $_POST['client_name_val']) && !isset($_POST['client_email_val']) && !isset($_POST['client_comp_val']) && !isset($_POST['client_desig_val']))
{
    return;
}
$cli_name_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['client_name_val'] );
update_post_meta($post_id, '_clientname_value', $cli_name_data);

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'astest_save_client_info' );
```

Comment: Instead of just `return` perform some logging or `print_r` or `wp_die` just so you can verify what's going where. Also, towards to middle you are checking that a `post_type` is equal to `page` but then you are checking the `edit_post` permission. Then later in the `else` clause you are checking the `edit_page` permission. Seems backwards.

Comment: try adding the priority as third parameter in add_action( 'save_post', 'astest_save_client_info',10 );
Sometimes it does help me :)

Comment: @ChrisHaas Now the values are storing in the database.. but it will not displaying on admin panel.

Comment: What do you mean by "not displaying in the admin panel"? Are you saying that `get_post_meta()` isn't returning your value? If you are getting blank for that, try `get_post_custom($post_id)` and dump that out.

Comment: Your code:
$clientname = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_clientname_value','true');
should be:
$clientname = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_clientname_value',true);
the last parameter is a boolean value and not a string.